# i got Whitelabel Error Page error when i hit http://localhost:8080/h2-console url in springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, h2

```
this is my application.properties file in src/main/resource


spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

i have added h2 dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

other one is Jpa dependency and web dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

the whole project is working well in postman but not working when i hit url in web browser

Comment: Can you add the logs output from both calls? Can you add the endpoint resource code with all the annotations?

Comment: no logs are displaying in console after hitting url @HaimRaman

Comment: in application properties change log to debug org.springframework.web=DEBUG , share the postman headers

Comment: after hitting url "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). "this shows in browser@HaimRaman

Comment: i am using  http://localhost:8080/h2-console url @HaimRaman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241194/discussion-between-ritu-mansata-and-haim-raman).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that this is a configuration issue.
Add the following to your application.properties

```
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

I would advice the following article
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/h2-database-example/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176805/in-xhtml-page-jsf-attribute-are-not-rendering  @Haim Raman